# Handing options with a comma with python's argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a python script that acts as a wrapper for GCC. Most of the options that GCC takes are straightforward to handle with argparse but I'm struggling with the "-Wl,option" option. I want it to store everything after the comma so I tried the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-Wl,", help="Option to pass to linker.")
known, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
print(known)
print(unknown)
```

However, if I run the script as follows:

```
python foo.py -Wl,foo
```

I get the following output:

```
Namespace(E=False, S=False, Wl,=None, c=False, optimization=None, shared=False, target=None)
['-Wl,foo']
```

which indicates that it didn't recognize the -Wl option.

I could change the add_argument line to read:

```
parser.add_argument("-W", help="Option to pass to linker.")
```

This works, storing "l,foo" in the W option, but GCC uses -W for warning flags and I want to keep those separated from the -Wl options.

I could run through the list of unknown args and handle them that way but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution to the problem. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of a simple `.replace(',',', ')` or `.replace(',',',=')` on all the args before passing them to argparse.  I think that one of these should do the trick.

Comment: While I didn't do exactly what you did, I did resort to targetted character replacement: `s.replace("-Wl","-Wl=")`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this with a CustomAction. http://pymotw.com/2/argparse/ has a nice example on how to do this.

Comment: The problem is that the CustomAction doesn't get called unless I have "-Wl,=foo".